# Separate data and store in array

Tags: c, string, hex, endianness, crc16

I'm having problem fixing the endianness of the value that I got.

What I'm thinking is separate a `WORD` to two, convert them to hex, and store them in an array.

The `WORD` is the "crc_data" that is return to my previous question(which has been answered).

[MODBUS RTU CRC16 calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564916/modbus-rtu-crc16-calculation/39566555#39566555)

For example:

I got a "result" data from the code of:

```
crc_data = 0A95
```

*Note: crc_data is datatype WORD

What I'm thinking is separate them into two, and make them as hex. Like this:

```
value_1 = 0x95
value_2 = 0x0A
```

Is there a way to do that? I read something about "BITWISE" operation, but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast to a `char*`. You would do it like this:

```
crc_data = 0x0A95
const unsigned char *k = (const unsigned char*) &crc_data;
value_1 = k[0];
value_2 = k[1];
```

The char pointer just lets you treat the data as though it was a string of bytes. You can then read them with the `[]` notation.

Another way is to use math to get the upper and lower parts. The bitshift operator `<<` will shitf your data down 8 bits. It's the same as dividing by 256.

```
crc_data = 0x0A95;
value_1 = crc_data & 0xFF;
value_2 = (crc_data >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

Another option is to use a union. Basically there are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks! But I change the (crc_data << 8) & 0xFF< to (crc_data >> 8) & 0xFF to adjust on what I need

Comment: Glad it helps! I edited my post with `>>`. That's what it should have been - just got mixed up - sorry.